# When using element.style = <some CSSStyleDeclaration> makes element dissapear

Tags: javascript, css, dom, typescript, angular

I use, (pls never mind the selector, I know it should be changed but it is found nevertheless).

```
 let leftArrow = <HTMLElement> document
  .querySelector('div[style="position: absolute; left: 6px; transform: skewX(22.6deg);' +
    ' transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; height: 24px; width: 10px;' +
    ' box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0px 1px 6px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"]');
```

Then I use:

```
let myStyle = leftArrow.style; //this gets me a CSSStyleDeclaration object
console.log(myStyle);         // those are equal objects
console.log(leftArrow.style); // those are equal objects
```

But when I do:

```
leftArrow.style = myStyle; //this should change nothing ?!
```

my element dissappears ?!

My goal is to use a class and then do sth like this:

```
leftArrow.style = this.getStyleFromClass(selector_to_find_class_name);
```

But after simple:

```
leftArrow.style = myStyle;
```

my element from upper one becomes :

```
<div></div>
```

which makes it basically not visible. Why ?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Are you trying to restore styles applied? You are going to need to approach that in a different manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is apply the original inline styles back. To do this, you can use [cssText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText) to get the values, and than you can set it back.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("x");
var backUp = div.style.cssText;
div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
div.style.color = "blue";
window.setTimeout( function () {
  div.style.cssText = backUp;
}, 4000);
```

```html
<div id="x" style="background-color:red">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> leftArrow.style = myStyle; //this should change nothing ?!

Yes but only if you have:

```
let myStyle = leftArrow.style; //this gets me a CSSStyleDeclaration object
letArrow.style = myStyle;
```

This is most likely not the code you have and you are generating the object on the fly. **Do not assign to style directly**. Instead assign to members of `style` e.g. `letArrow.style.color = "red"`